# Allow wifi weak signal connect

Tags: wi-fi, cyanogenmod, connection-issues, network-signal, zte-blade

I have 2 ZTE Blades (with 512 Mb RAM) and CM7 **2.3.7** (Kang) from BurgerZ ROM installed on them.

One of them - my girl's - can connect to home and other (public i.e. McDonalds) wifi AP's even if it's signal is just one bar (it's about 6-7 meters from home router and there are two perpendicular walls on the way). But my can't do that even if 4 bars. (Also, if it can help, same situation with the gps fixes.)

I wondering why two same devices have such different behavior?

I heard that there are some patch or something to allow android to connect to wifi AP with weak signal but can't find this solution.
I know thac ICS have an option `Avoid poor connections` but I'm not on ICS and don't want to flash it on my Blade.

Please, if you have any information or solution about that, help me to fix my device.

Comment: I believe that option was there even before ICS. Is the one that can connect the one running CM7?

Comment: Both of them have identical rom flashed ([cm-7.2.0-RC1-Blade-KANG-13APR](http://test.burgerz.pro/zte-blade/cm7/)). Both devices was bought in one time in one place.

Comment: Oh, I see. I misread the first sentence. Have you tried doing a factory reset on the one with the wifi issues? (Note that doing so will wipe all your data, so do a backup first)

Comment: Do both devices have the same _radio_?

Comment: @Michael Hampton, Is `radio` hardware or software part and where can I check if they're the same or not?

Comment: @Michael Hampton, both have `Baseband version` — "P729BB01".
Because of using S2E with ext-partition mounted as EXT4, I cannot fully backup in CWM (Blade or CWM can't backup ext4 partitions), I can't check if wifi and gps may work like on first device.

My suggestion was backed up and restored system settings (by Titanium Backup) from stock 2.2 Froyo's. Is it possible?

Comment: @Крайст I'd be very careful restoring system settings across different ROMs -- you easily can break things this way (did that one time). If you're going to try, make sure to enable the "migration" feature of TB.

Comment: Guys, I made wipe and flashed the same clean rom (CM7 2.3.7 Kang (by BurgerZ)) with no restoration of backed up data. Nothing has changed. Also I'd flashed alternative kernel (http://blade.windows98.co.uk/) and things were the same. One thing I learned is that's not software problem. I've seen the forum topic said about broken antenna's connection (http://www.modaco.com/topic/322176-very-poor-wifi-reception-not-disconnecting-issue/). Found back cover on ebay for 1 GBP (+ 7 GBP for packaging and postage - about $12,6). Maybe I should buy it or is it a waste of money?

Comment: Maybe someone knows answer about subject? How for android to allow connection with poor signal? I've heard about this option but don't know where it is and had googling without success.